# Name of a sci-fi story about cannibalism

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a story in which unwanted infants were sold as food in open markets, although I don't think that was the main theme of the story.  It was published in a monthly science fiction magazine (i.e. Analog, Fantasy & Science Fiction, Astounding Stories, etc), so it could have been a short story, novella, or serial.  It was in English.  I think it was in the 1970's, but I've been reading science fiction since 1954 and it could have been anytime since then.

I thnk they were sold alive. I don't know why they were sold.  They were infants, i.e. under a year old.  The planet was not Earth.  The inhabitants were intelligent, but I don't recall whether they were native or colonists.  I remember a scene in which a woman was grocery shopping and checked an infant's leg for tenderness by squeezing it.

Comment: I thnk they were sold alive.  The only other detail I recall is that it didn't take place on Earth.  I remember a scene in which a woman was grocery shopping and checked an infant's leg for tenderness by squeezing it.

Comment: This story sounds really 'wrong'. Interesting, but 'wrong'.

Comment: No arguement there, Mooz.  I just need to track it down so I can get it out of my head.  I'm also hoping it's not as 'wrong' as I remember it being.

Comment: The details you added in a comment should be incorporated into the question. The "edit" button is right below the story-identification tag.

Comment: Thank you, user14111.  I'm still learning how to use this website.

Comment: In the book Courtship Rite they bought babies at the market for like wedding feasts etc. That was set on another planet where the human settlers had turned to cannibalism. Lots of short chapters and some were almost small stories on their own. It was written first as a serial in Analog in the early eighties.

Comment: You might want to check out "The Men in the Jungle " by Norman Spinrad.  It's about a ruthless man and his two hangers-on who want to start a revolution on a planet run by a truly nasty little theocracy. The  planet has no edible animals so the ruling elite get their meat from farming and devouring slave children. The rebels are rebelling so they can eat human meat too!

Comment: @Dennis thanks, I was flashing back to some very unpleasant story that this question reminded me of, and I think it was "Jungle".  Was driving me crazy.

Comment: Thank you all, especially Danny3414 and John Rennie, for your comments and help.  I checked reviews on another site and one person said she had been somewhat taken aback by the phrase "roast baby".  Based on both your descriptions and her comment, I believe Courtship Rite is indeed the story I'm looking for.  If it isn't available at the library, I see I can buy it on eBay.  Thank you all again.

Comment: There's also "Starhammer" by Christopher Rowley which has the following in it ........""Cannibalism is a constant threat here. Women sell their own newborns to the butcher, the dead seldom need be buried or cremated.""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of the comments have mentioned the book [Courtship Rite](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2192) by Donald Kingsbury, and it does sound very similar to your description. But I cannot find any scene where a woman buying a baby squeezes it to check for tenderness.

The background is a vaguely Arabian Nights setting. There is a tribe called the Kaiel (named after an insect) who eat humans of low *kalothi* - I can't remember exactly how *kalothi* is defined but it's basically genetic fitness.

The Kaiel have also bred *monster-women* specifically for the task of producing children for meat. I'm not sure it is ever explained exactly what these are, though I'd guess they are humans bred for the purpose.

There isn't a lot said about the selling of babies at the market because it isn't a major focus of the book, and as I mentioned above I can't find any scene like the one you describe. There is a scene where the carcass of one of the *monster-women* is being butchered for sale:

> Oelita asked to see the back room where the meat was prepared. She spoke to the
> butchers gently, never showing her mind, searching theirs. They were jovial about their task as they prepared the carcass of a “machine,” the name the Kaiel
> seemed to have given the genetic monster-women who bore the babies for the
> creches.
> “Ye covet a block o’ that thigh? Cost ye an arm and a leg, it will.” He laughed.
> “Was she very old?”
> “This un, ye’ll have’t’ boil. She mebe 30-40 chile down the road.”

Or another scene:

> Oelita was curious to visit the meat market. No such place existed in Sorrow. There the only meat was given away at the Temple when it was freshly available, or one waited to be invited to a funeral. Here it was sold by the temples at atrocious prices. Noe bought a small jar containing two pickled baby tongues.

But that's the closest I could find.

It's also worth noting that the book was published in 1982 so it's at the edge of your time frame.